# Add items to the ArrayList but don't save them

Tags: java, jsp

From the form of index.html I take username and password and add them in two different ArrayLists, namely 'users' and 'passw', of the jsp page "supporto.jsp". Then from here I do the redirection in "registration.jsp" and so far everything works. When I repeat the operation adding new things to the array and print them, it shows me that the array contains only one element (and not two) and shows me only the last one inserted. Why?

index.html

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>
      Registrazione
    </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h3> Scegli un username ed una password per registrarti: </h3>
    <form action="appoggio.jsp" method="post">
      <p> <input type="text" name="user"> Username </p>
      <p> <input type="password" name="pwd"> Password </p>
      <p> <input type="submit" value="Invia"> </p>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

appoggio.jsp

```
<head>
    <title>
      Benvenuto/a
    </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%
      String usern = request.getParameter("user");
      String pass = request.getParameter("pwd");
      String nextPage;

      ArrayList<String> utenti = new ArrayList<String>(); //qui dentro salvo tutti gli usern
      ArrayList<String> passw = new ArrayList<String>(); //qui dentro salvo tutte le pass
    %>
    <%
      utenti.add(usern);
      passw.add(pass);
      request.setAttribute("usern", utenti);
      request.setAttribute("pass", passw);
      nextPage = "/registrazione.jsp";
      RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher(nextPage);
      rd.forward(request, response);
    %>
  </body>
</html>
```

registrazione.jsp

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>
      Registrazione
    </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
    <%
      ArrayList utenti = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("usern");
      //utenti.add(request.getParameter("usern"));
    %>
    <h1> Ciao <%= utenti %> </h1>
    <a href="index.html"> CLicca </a>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time the page is loaded a new array list is created. You need a controller so when the form is submitted a method saves those values

Comment: How you do it??

Comment: i don't know what kind of project you are doing. with spring or other frameworks you annotate @Controller on a java class and various other things that are too much for this post.

Comment: Isn't there an easy way to not lose what I add in an array?

Comment: What kind of server are you using? i'd reccoment going to start.spring.io put WEB for dependencies. download the project and add those files to resources folder and create a controller class and maybe read some things. if you get that far let me know and i can help more.

Comment: ok and you deploy an application. is it just those jsp's or do you have any java files?